# Current "Flow" track name using Deezer NativeSDK

Tags: python, deezer

I'm using the Deezer NativeSDK Python wrapper available here : https://github.com/deezer/native-sdk-samples

I'm playing user's "Flow" radio `deezer_app.load_content("dzradio:///user-12345".encode('utf-8'))` . How can I recover the playing track information or at least the track id ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is available through the `QUEUELIST_TRACK_SELECTED` event.
The function `Player.event_track_selected_dzapiinfo(event)` will return the JSON of the current track selected.

I have updated the PythonSample of https://github.com/deezer/native-sdk-samples to illustrate it. (you can check myDeezerApp.py)

The corresponding SDK function wrappers have been added in (deezer_import.py)

```
libdeezer.dz_player_event_track_selected_dzapiinfo.argtypes = [c_void_p]
libdeezer.dz_player_event_track_selected_dzapiinfo.restype = c_char_p
```